# Silicon Image Raid5 search for data recovery options

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid5, data-recovery, sata, raid-controller

In a HP server with windows 2008-R2. There is a PCI Silicon Image SATA raid controller with 4 SATA disks.
In the controller is a config to make them in a Raid5 config.
Windows is seeing them as 1 drive.

When restarting the server this morning, one of the drives was "jumping" (mechanical). After the noise, the screen was showing that one of the disks in the raid was missing. (this was a wrong conclusion)

While hardware restart, this time with hood open, the "missing" disk is the only one with mechanic vibration. (the reason for wrong conclusion).
When continue the start, the system is showing 4 devices but no raid volume.

I was afraid that the jumping disk was "holding" the connect of the raid volume. SATA is hotswap, so I took the "errordisk" off the raidcontroller.
Directly, the software makes an event "device missing". Logical. I reconnect it.
When I connect, I see that i disconnected the wrong drive. Not the errordisk but an healthy one.
I repeat the process for the errordisk.
At that moment I hear the sound again and follow my ears.
The "jumping" comes from the spare disk in the HP array. Founding out about the wrong conclusion

When I restart the system, again, there is no raid volume. I go to the controller "bios". There, the options are limited. I see 4 devices that are working, and I see the configuration of a raid5 set over 4 disks.
Back in windows, I start the software.
There I see that 1 disk is active but not part of the raid5 anymore. The rest has an existing raid set. (see picture)
The system is telling me that all 4 disks are health. The system tells me that there is a raid5 set over 3 disks.
But the rebuild button is gray.
When I try the: "convert legacy raid group" I get an error.

What can I try to do to rebuild the volume and not lose the data?

[Print screen of situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kfzt.png)

Update 1: The existing backup is not recent enough and incomplete. Data can be taken from other places, but the reconstruction will take a lot of time and be incomplete. Updating the server to newer version is ongoing talk where the move has consequences for the people using the server on different levels. They know they need to, but they are delaying.

Comment: Take it to the professional recovery service. You want your data? Pay for it. It's too much for you? You just determined how much your data costs. If it's isn't valuable enough, don't recover. And, if you want to exercise, at least, take images of all disks in a current state (probably it's worth including dead one). Yes, that will require a lot of space, but that will guarantee you that if some information is recoverable you never lose the chance to recover it eventually.

Comment: moreover, running a dead horse (2008 is EOL already) , the backup should be able to recover the the data... And oh.. no backup? no... you know the drill

Answer (score 1):

Check serial number of the faulty disk the controller told you it's faulty and validate while the server if OFF before restarting the server.

> While hardware restart, this time with hood open, the "missing" disk
> is the only one with mechanic vibration. (the reason for wrong
> conclusion). When continue the start, **the system is showing 4
> devices but no raid volume.**

All the step you did to recover after the text in bold are futile sadly, as while the first reboot, the raid array seem to have been flushed from the controller.

Keep in mind a drive can tick and make noise under normal use. This is not the main factor to detect the failing drive. Next time if the controller told a disk with s/n X is fail, use that as a way to find it. If a disk next to it make cringe sound, you can assume your array might fail soon too, especially in a raid5 setup, where you can have just one member offline. Sadly the cringe sound is a warning to make sure you have a backup near.

My advise is to restore from a backup your data and possibly ditch that faulty controller, and while at it upgrade to a supported OS.

Comment: I was hoping for better news. But okay. Strange thing is that the screenshot is from the last moment. The screenshot gives the impression that the volume is still there.

Comment: @SmartThinker maybe someone got a better idea via the controller cli, as I agree it see a legacy raid settings, but the fact it stated up with all disk in standalone and no volume, is a really really bad sign like I state, it's like you swaped a controller inside your server without knowledge of the raid 5 array you had, AND the disk configuration inside each disk was not set to an array

Comment: I restarted the server again. There it is talking about 2 settings. When I go to Logical drive setup. It highlights 0,1, and 3 and "Invalid Raid drive". And when I move to 2: "Reserved drives". The controller itself is combining the 3 in the highlights!?!?!?!? To confirm: there is no controller switched or disk switched. only 2 disks disconnected/connected.

Comment: @SmartThinker Look like how I told it, time to scrap that controler sadly..  as usually disconnecting 2 drive your array would be lost, in a fail state without possibility of recovering. It's not that way for you, as like you told before you disconnect stuff, it was already stating it had no raid, and now it's just lying around as invalid raid, and the reboot before the drive was in a old raid setup